# Initial value problem with heterogeneous initial values

Tags: differential-equations, cauchy-problem

In all the references I checked the standard initial value problem for an ODE is stated as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} 
y'=F(y,t)\\
y(t_0)=y_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for some $F:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and under hypotheses on $F$ one can conclude existence, uniqueness, etc.

My question is: is there a standard way to address the problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} 
y'=F(y,t)\\
y_i(t_i)=y_{0,i}, \quad i=1,\ldots, n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where the "initial condition" is not given for the **same** $t_0$ for all the components of $y$, but at different $t_is$? where by address I mean, to begin with, check existence and uniqueness conditions, e.g. do some version of Peano, Osgood and Caratheodory theorems hold? any reference would be appreciated.
I asked the same question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3485504/system-of-initial-value-problems-with-initial-conditions-at-different-t-0
and now I am trying MO.

My thoughts:

For example, using the integral formulation of the problem, in the case $n=2$ for simplicity, we have:

\begin{align}
y_1(t)&=y_1(t_{01})+\int_{t_{01}}^t F_1(y_1(s),y_2(s),s)d s\\
y_2(t)&=y_2(t_{02})+\int_{t_{02}}^t F_2(y_1(s),y_2(s),s)d s
\end{align}

Now if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are Lipschitz with constant $L<1/(2|t_{01}-t_{02}|)$ on the interval $I=[t_{01}-t_{02}]$ then on $I$ there exist a unique solution via the standard argument by the contraction mapping theorem. In fact define a norm on $C^1(I, \mathbb{R}^2)$ by $\lVert y-z\rVert=\max_t{|y_1(t)-z_1(t)|}+\max_t{|y_2(t)-z_2(t)|}$. Then, if $T$ is the integral operator associated with the IVP:
\begin{equation}
\lVert Ty-Tz\rVert\le\max_t\int_{t01}^t|F_1(y(s))-F_1(z(s)|d s+\max_t{\int_{t02}^t|F_2(y(s))-F_2(z(s)|d s}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\le2\max_t L\int_I(|y_1(s))-z_1(s)|+|y_2(s))-z_2(s)|)d s
\end{equation}
if $t \in [t_{01},t_{02}]$

Is this the standard way to proceed? Is there any more general/better way?